# What Is gps data?

Tags: gps, statistics, regression

A very basic question here, what are gps coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS coordinates (latitude, longitude) are related to an elipsoid (WGS84), so not a perfect sphere. Since the difference to a sphere is very little most formulas use the spherical approach, or even  linear cartesian mathematics.

For regions outside the poles (< latitude 80) and for traces which do not overlap the datum limit (border between longitude -180 and 180) and 
for an interpolation / regression range that do not exceed 10km, a linear apporoach can be used.
At least a simple transformation to cartesian space is needed to overcome the fact that 1 degree of longitude corresponds to a different number of meters as one degree of latitude.
Such simple transformation multiply the longitude value with cos(medium latitude).

If the traces exceed the range of 10km, a more complex transformation is needed. E.g UTM transofrmtaion gives cartesian coordinate in the span of 3 degrees of longitude.

This is all is valid as long as you don't need to consider the altitude value of a GPS coordinate. (Aero plane traces would need that).
In the later case a ECEF (Earth centered, Earth fixed) transformed coordinatres can be used to make  a linear interpolation and to use standard cartesian coordinate mathematics.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Installing a Global Positioning System (GPS) device is crucial for the growth of the companies. A comprehensive GPS tracking software with scalability and a fully automated end-to-end solution can provide you with all the relevant information that can cater to all your tracking needs. Any organization that needs commercial vehicles, tends to engage in fleet management solutions to track and monitor their fleet operations with advanced GPS tracking.

Comment: If you add proper indentation then it can be easier for reader to understand.